# As of July 30, 2019, the standalone App Engine SDK is deprecated. How-to migrate pycharm python2.7 apps

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pycharm, appcfg

AppCfg will become unavailable for download on July 30, 2020.

For appcfg commands you have to Migrate from AppCfg to gcloud command line.

But this link returns 404: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/migrating-from-appcfg-to-gcloud

And will pycharm appengine support also migrate soon?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the link has been already updated, please try this one:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sdk-gcloud-migration

Regarding PyCharm App Engine support you'll have to check in [JetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/google-app-engine.html).

Comment: PyCharm App Engine support still depends on appcfg.py.